# If ${\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\left| {{\lambda _i}} \right|} ^2} = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{\sigma _i}^2} \Rightarrow$A is normal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in {M_n}$ have eigenvalues ${\lambda _1}.....{\lambda _n}$ and singular values ${\sigma _1}.....{\sigma _n}$ and suppose ${\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\left| {{\lambda _i}} \right|} ^2} = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{\sigma _i}^2}  $.Why $A$ is normal?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Unitarily triangularise $A$ and calculate the trace of $AA^\ast$.